# PHP json_encode unknown error

Tags: php

I am returning results from a MySql database in PHP that I would like to use the **json_encode** function to turn into a string to pass back for another page's usage to display options within a SELECT element. However, the json_encode method fails and my page is not rendering properly. By that I mean I receive a generic IIS error from the cgi-bin process. I have error capturing setup within my script but the error generated is not boiling up far enough to be shown and I am not sure why.

The basis of my question is how can I make **json_encode** like the information below or do I need to roll my own encoder to deal with it?

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [productID] => 2
            [optionID] => 1
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [productID] => 2
            [optionID] => 2
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [productID] => 2
            [optionID] => 3
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [productID] => 2
            [optionID] => 4
        )

)
```

Comment: the real error reason *should* be logged somewhere, probably worth searching

Comment: Which PHP version are you using? json_encode is available from PHP 5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spell **json_encode** correctly and it works MUCH better... dummy me.